# Place json in String variable

Tags: java, json

I want to place all my Json content in String variable in below format.

```
String inputJSON = "{
\"billingAddress\":{\"city\":\"\",\"country\":\"\",\"postalCode\":\"\",\"state\":\"\",\"streetAddress\":\"\"},
\"shippingAddress\":{\"city\":\"\",\"country\":\"\",\"postalCode\":\"\",\"state\":\"\",\"streetAddress\":\"\"},
\"personAddress\":{\"city\":\"\",\"country\":\"\",\"postalCode\":\"\",\"state\":\"\",\"streetAddress\":\"\"},
\"customerStatus\":\"\",
\"createdDate\":\""+((String)globalMap.get("Json.Date"))+"\"";
```

May I know why am getting error in this regarding to complete double quotes ? I think whole string is completed or covered by double quotes. I want to place my json in this format only, May I know please what am missing or doing wrong ?

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca, Can you please show how it should be with one example ?

Comment: Sorry, wrong language. See the other answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sadly Java doesn't support multi-line `String` declaration. You need to use `+` to concatenate lines

```
String inputJSON = "{"
    + "\"billingAddress\":{\"city\":\"\",\"country\":\"\",\"postalCode\":\"\",\"state\":\"\",\"streetAddress\":\"\"}," 
    + "\"shippingAddress\":{\"city\":\"\",\"country\":\"\",\"postalCode\":\"\",\"state\":\"\",\"streetAddress\":\"\"}," 
    + "\"personAddress\":{\"city\":\"\",\"country\":\"\",\"postalCode\":\"\",\"state\":\"\",\"streetAddress\":\"\"}," 
    + "\"customerStatus\":\"\",\"createdDate\":\""+((String)globalMap.get("Json.Date"))+"\"";
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to add `"+"` at the end of every line to join them in a valid way:

These 3 are the same:

```
String s = "abcdef";
String s = "abc"+"def";
String s = "abc"+
           "def";
```

So for you example:

```
String s =
    "{ "+
    "\"billingAddress\":{\"city\":\"\",\"country\":\"\",\"postalCode\":\"\",\"state\":\"\",\"streetAddress\":\"\"},"+
    "\"shippingAddress\":{\"city\":\"\",\"country\":\"\",\"postalCode\":\"\",\"state\":\"\",\"streetAddress\":\"\"},"+
    "\"personAddress\":{\"city\":\"\",\"country\":\"\",\"postalCode\":\"\",\"state\":\"\",\"streetAddress\":\"\"},"+
    "\"customerStatus\":\"\","+
    "\"createdDate\":\""+((String)globalMap.get("Json.Date"))+"\"}";
```

Also you were missing a `}` at the end to have a valid JSON string

If you print out the String above you get (once formatted)

```
{
  "billingAddress": {
    "city": "",
    "country": "",
    "postalCode": "",
    "state": "",
    "streetAddress": ""
  },
  "shippingAddress": {
    "city": "",
    "country": "",
    "postalCode": "",
    "state": "",
    "streetAddress": ""
  },
  "personAddress": {
    "city": "",
    "country": "",
    "postalCode": "",
    "state": "",
    "streetAddress": ""
  },
  "customerStatus": "",
  "createdDate": "pop"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Java does not support multi-line String literals (yet). So, each line needs to be a complete String, enclosed in double-quotes, and each line needs to be concatenated using a '+'.

```
    final String inputJSON = "{" +
    "\"billingAddress\":{\"city\":\"\",\"country\":\"\",\"postalCode\":\"\",\"state\":\"\",\"streetAddress\":\"\"}," +
    "\"shippingAddress\":{\"city\":\"\",\"country\":\"\",\"postalCode\":\"\",\"state\":\"\",\"streetAddress\":\"\"}," +
    "\"personAddress\":{\"city\":\"\",\"country\":\"\",\"postalCode\":\"\",\"state\":\"\",\"streetAddress\":\"\"}," +
    "\"customerStatus\":\"\"," +
    "\"createdDate\":\""+((String)globalMap.get("Json.Date"))+"\"";
```

Maybe more readable:

```
final String inputJSON =
    "{" +
    "    \"billingAddress\": {" +
    "        \"city\":\"\"," +
    "        \"country\":\"\"," +
    "        \"postalCode\":\"\"," +
    "        \"state\":\"\"," +
    "        \"streetAddress\":\"\"" +
    "    }," +
    "    \"shippingAddress\": {" +
    "        \"city\":\"\"," +
    "        \"country\":\"\"," +
    "        \"postalCode\":\"\"," +
    "        \"state\":\"\"," +
    "        \"streetAddress\":\"\"" +
    "    }," +
    "    \"personAddress\": {" +
    "        \"city\":\"\"," +
    "        \"country\":\"\"," +
    "        \"postalCode\":\"\"," +
    "        \"state\":\"\"," +
    "        \"streetAddress\":\"\"" +
    "    }," +
    "    \"customerStatus\":\"\"," +
    "    \"createdDate\": \"" + ((String)globalMap.get("Json.Date")) + "\"" +
    "}";
```

With this format, it was easy to see the closing '}' was missing as well.

Good luck.